# how play and visualize audio streaming between browsers via peerconnection?

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, webrtc, visualizer

I am using webrtc for create peerconnection and stream audio between browsers, but how can I visualize and play the audio stream with a visualizer(for example wave form) to both the transmitting and the receiving?
Someone knows some example?

Thanks

Comment: This question was helpful for visualizing streaming audio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479560/creating-an-audio-visualizer-using-html5

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at @cwilso's excellent demos on [webaudiodemos.appspot.com](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/), in particular [Audio Recorder](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html) (which inputs audio from getUserMedia to Web Audio, analyses the data and draws to a canvas element) and [Live Input Effects](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/input/index.html) (which does something similar but with WebGL for the visualisation).

@paul-lewis's [Audio Room](http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/audio-room/) also uses WebGL.

Comment: I am using the example "Live Input Effects" and work fine but only I hear to myself. I don't hear audio stream added from other peerconnection. You know some example?

Comment: Using a stream from RTCPeerConnection as input to Web Audio is in progress (in Chrome at least) but not supported yet.

Comment: @SamDutton Has any progress been made on this? (peerConnection + webAudio) Is there somewhere I can follow for updates?